# MongoDB - Get the sum of an object in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I'm very new to MongoDB, I'm trying to get the total price and promo of the below MongoDB data with `document.collection.find` and `$add` functionality:

Data:

```
[
  {
    "catalog":"A",
    "book":[
    {
      "title":"Mermaid yang terdampar",
      "price":90000,
      "promo":15000
    },
    {
      "title":"Srigala berbulu domba",
      "price":30000,
      "promo":15000
    }
  }
]
```

And my expected result would be sth like this:

```
[
  {
    "catalog": "A",
    "totalPrice": 140000,
    "totalPromo": 32000
  },
]
```

Does anybody ever encounter a similar issue? I'm confused with the query :)

Answer (score 4):

For `.find()` query, you can direct use the `$sum` operator.

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  catalog: 1,
  totalSum: {
    $sum: "$book.price"
  },
  totalPromo: {
    $sum: "$book.promo"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pT2ItvHIlNa)

Comment: No problem, this answer provides the sum of the book array for **each** document (calculate under each document). If you are looking for sum based on the catalog, you need the aggregation query with `$group` which covers in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

use aggregate

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tempId",
        "totalPrice": { 
            "$sum": { "$sum": "$book.price" } 
        },
        "totalPromo": { 
            "$sum": { "$sum": "$book.promo" } 
        }
    } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [$group (aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group)

```
db.getCollection('catlog').aggregate([{ 
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        catalog: { $first: "$catalog" },
        totalPrice: { "$sum": { $sum: "$book.price" } },
        totalPromo: { "$sum": { $sum: "$book.promo" } }
    }
}])
```

Output will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6247b33cffc5b6f714769fbb"),
    "catalog" : "A",
    "totalPrice" : 120000,
    "totalPromo" : 30000
}
```